# Can't Change Theme And White Screen When Activating Any Plugin

Tags: errors, fatal-error

I ran into an issue. When I am trying to activate a plugin, **any** plugin, I am getting a white screen. I tried to change theme and it just won't let me.

I then went to `wp-config.php` and turned on debugging and these are the errors I am getting when trying to change theme:

> Notice: yith_wcwl_products cookie cannot be set - headers already sent
>   by
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php
>   on line 1 in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php
>   on line 835
>
> Notice: Constant WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT already defined in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-config.php on line 91
>
> Notice: Constant AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL already defined in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-config.php on line 92
>
> Notice: Constant WP_POST_REVISIONS already defined in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-config.php on line 93
>
> Notice: Constant EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS already defined in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-config.php on line 94
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:1)
>   in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/plugins/flexible-shipping/classes/flexible-shipping-plugin.php
>   on line 169
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:1)
>   in /home1/website/public_html/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1124

These are the errors when trying the activate a plugin:

> Notice: yith_wcwl_products cookie cannot be set - headers already sent
>   by
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php
>   on line 1 in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php
>   on line 835
>
> Notice: Constant WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT already defined in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-config.php on line 91
>
> Notice: Constant AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL already defined in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-config.php on line 92
>
> Notice: Constant WP_POST_REVISIONS already defined in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-config.php on line 93
>
> Notice: Constant EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS already defined in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-config.php on line 94
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:1)
>   in
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/plugins/flexible-shipping/classes/flexible-shipping-plugin.php
>   on line 169
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:1)
>   in /home1/website/public_html/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1124
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:1)
>   in /home1/website/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1219
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home1/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:1)
>   in /home1/website/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1219

My `flatsome-child/function.php` file is empty.

I am assuming there errors creates more problems throughout the website.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned flatsome-child/function.php is empty, but is it completely empty, i.e. is there any whitespace in there at all? This article might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: The problem when activating a plugin or theme was caused apparently because of white-spaces. I uploaded the original `function.php` given with the theme and problem solved. Though I still get the already defined stuff. I will look at the article you mentioned and will update soon. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The white-spaces also solved the `headers already sent` error.
Can you please post an answer so I can mark this as solved?

Comment: Glad it's fixed @Omer, just posted as the answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in this SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag of a file can cause a "headers already sent error".

In particular, if the error message is indicating the problem is on line one of the file, this can point to leading whitespace before the first `<?php` tag (mentioned in point 3 of the above post).

Removing this whitespace from the file should correct the problem.